# npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:

Tags: laravel, npm, npm-install

I was creating a new laravel project and while installing the npm this error occurred

Command that I ran was `npm install`

- Laravel Framework 8.6.0

- Node Version:- 8.10.0

**Error:-**

```
npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
loadDevDep:vue-template-c - |################---------------------------------|
WARN engine cross-env@7.0.2: wanted: {"node":">=10.14","npm":">=6","yarn":">=1"}npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm ERR! Linux 5.4.0-48-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code EMISSINGARG

npm ERR! typeerror Error: Missing required argument #1
npm ERR! typeerror     at andLogAndFinish (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:31:3)
npm ERR! typeerror     at fetchPackageMetadata (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:51:22)
npm ERR! typeerror     at resolveWithNewModule (/usr/share/npm/lib/install/deps.js:456:12)
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/lib/install/deps.js:457:7
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:37:12
npm ERR! typeerror     at addRequestedAndFinish (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:82:5)
npm ERR! typeerror     at returnAndAddMetadata (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:117:7)
npm ERR! typeerror     at pickVersionFromRegistryDocument (/usr/share/npm/lib/fetch-package-metadata.js:134:20)
npm ERR! typeerror     at /usr/share/npm/node_modules/iferr/index.js:13:50
npm ERR! typeerror This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR! typeerror     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/kabir/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/bin/White0.1/npm-debug.log
```

**package.json:-**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^7.0",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.20.1",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    }
}
```

I don't have any idea what's wrong, Please help. I hope this information is enough. do ask if more is needed.

Comment: @jenkem469 I've added in the question

Comment: @jenkem469 I'm sorry I don't understand. Can you please explain what else you need. This is the full output (full error)

Comment: @jenkem469 Yes this is the full error after I typed ``npm install``

Comment: @jenkem469 I've added the image

Comment: please share your package.json

Comment: @jenkem469 added in my question

Comment: @AnonymousChatbox What's your node version?

Comment: @Rob Node Version:- **8.10.0**

Comment: Update your `node` version and `npm` version and it will be fixed.

Comment: can you tell me a command to update them @Rob

Comment: @AnonymousChatbox Are you on Mac || Windows || Linux?

Comment: @Rob Linux Ubuntu

Comment: @AnonymousChatbox I don't remember exactly, may be `npm install -g n`. Please do a google search and you will find thousand answers on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is because you're using an older version of node & NPM that one (or more) of your dependencies doesn't support.

Using the same versions as you (Node@8.10.0 and NPM@3.5.2) I also get an error when running `npm install`.

With more recent versions (Node@12.15.0 and NPM@6.13.4) your `package.json` installs without a problem.